# How to sync last N files from remote directory with RSYNC or LFTP

Tags: linux, rsync, lftp

I have files in directory: 1500.txt, 1501.txt, 1502.txt etc.

I have to sync only last N files from remote directory to local directory via SSH, last files - files ordered by name DESC (1502.txt, 1501.txt etc).

Old files from local directory (which not copying in this iteration) must be deleted

LFTP has option order by name but it doesn't has file limit option, may be RSYNC has this option?

Comment: You may be better off initiating the transfer from the remote because first you need to find the files you want to sync. Check this https://serverfault.com/questions/581243/how-can-i-manipulate-the-find-command-to-find-the-directories-the-found-file

Comment: Yes, i could do that, and what will be solution?

Comment: The solution is outlined in the answer. Of course you may want to adjust it to your needs but basically you need to run that command on the remote. You can also use CRON to automate.

Comment: As i understand i could use something like this: find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort | tail -n 40 -exec rsync -av -R {} /destination/ \; to copy last 40 files from local directory to remote directory, but how to remove old files from remote directory width rsync?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.